# Assigning results of pd.read_sql_query to list of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

I have a list of sqlite3 databases and would like to be able to read each of them into separate Pandas Dataframe with a loop but so far my method does not populate the dataframes. I guess it has to do with working on copy rather than reference but can't find a good way for this to work.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

db_1 = 'db1.db'
db_2 = 'db2.db'

df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()

db_df_name = [(db_1, df_1, 'df_raw'), (db_2, df_2, 'df_processed')]

for (db, df, name) in db_df_name:
with sqlite3.connect(db, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) as connection:
    df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from messages;", connection)
    print(f'Database {name} processed')
```

Comment: With current code, df_1.info() returns
     <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
     Index: 0 entries  
     Empty DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could explain better what you want to do, i can help more.

Try this, and correct me if it doesn't work:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

# Assuming that you have two databases... 
# which i don't understand cause you use the 
# same query below with the same table.
dbs = ['db1.db','db2.db']

db_df_name = [(dbs[0], 'df_raw'), (dbs[1],'df_processed')]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()

df_list = []
for db, name in db_df_name:
    with sqlite3.connect(db, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES) as connection:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("select * from messages;", connection)
        print(f'Database {name} processed')
        df_list = df_list.append(df.copy())

df_1, df_2 = df_list
print(df_1)
print(df_2)
```

When you use this: `for db, name in db_df_name`, *db* is scope variable, it's not *df_1* it self, assuming you are passing this structure (that's the reason i remove it):

```
db_df_name = [(db_1, df_1, 'df_raw'), (db_2, df_2, 'df_processed')]
```

So when you are assigning `df = ...`, *df_1* will be Empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help Lucas, the main goal here is to read each database in a separate dataframe i.e. db_1 content in df_1 and db_2 content in df_2.

Comment: Got it, i thought you wanted to append both dbs in one DataFrame, i will edit then...